# How does Fliike Smiirl counter mechanism work

Tags: mechanism, stepper-motor

First of all please see this video : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n0dkn4ZIQVg

I think there is ony one stepper motor -or servo- working in the mechanisim. But as you can see each flip counter works alone and separately.

It is not like classical counter mechanism like this : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rjWfIiaOFR4

How does it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you are asking how a ["split-flap display"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/split-flap_display) on things like the 
[Flapit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flapit), the [Smiirl Fliike](http://www.wired.com/2013/08/lets-make-sure-everyone-knows-how-popular-you-are-with-the-smiirl-fliike/), etc. works.

### flip clocks

Some [flip clocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/flip_clock) -- ["Retro Flip Clock"](http://www.instructables.com/id/Cool-Exposed-Retro-Flip-Clock/), etc. -- use a single motor and a ["carry gear mechanism"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rjWfIiaOFR4) so they can only count forward and backward (or in some cases only forward) in sequential order.

### general flip displays

The video you show seems to spin the 100s digit, the 10s digit, and the 1 digit independently of the other digits,
like split-flap displays indicating arrivals and departures at airports and railway stations.

I suspect it is possible to have a mechanism with a total of one or two motors to independently select one at a time of a large number of letter/digit flip sections, and then flip that section an appropriate number of times, perhaps something like the way the [Armatron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armatron) somehow managed to control a bunch of joints with a total of one single motor.

However, in practice,
my understanding is that such displays typically have a dedicated motor for each letter/digit.
For example, [Markus' split-flap display](http://www.jave.de/blog2/?p=111) (via ["Driving an 8-digit split flap display"](http://hackaday.com/2011/01/03/driving-an-8-digit-split-flap-display/) ), [Tom Lynch's split-flap display](http://unknowndomain.co.uk/category/design/split-flap-display/) (via ["Split flap display: if you can’t find it, built it"](http://hackaday.com/2014/10/04/split-flap-display-if-cant-find-it-built-it/) ), the ["Signal-to-noise" mechanism](http://www.wired.com/2013/12/this-exhibit-turns-old-school-travel-schedule-boards-into-art/#slideid-317641), etc. each use a dedicated motor for each letter/digit section.